# How to draw this block diagram in LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

I am writing my thesis by LaTex, I have searched in many forums, but can not find, how to draw block scheme like on the picture. Could you please give me hints or commands, which i can use in this case? Thank you very much in advance. [image]

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{90pt}%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


% Define block styles

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, 
    text width=40em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (step 1) {1. We start the CUEs service loop by computing the priority index for each CUE m and for each sub-channel n according to (3.7).};

    \node [block, below of=step 1] (step 2) {2. We serve CUE m with sub-channel n fulfilling condition (3.8).};
    \node [block, below of=step 2] (step 3) {3. We remove sub-channel n and CUE m from the service list of TTI t, since we have to serve other CUEs with different (non-allocated) sub-channels.};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (step 1) -- (step 2);
    \path [line] (step 2) -- (step 3);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, everyone.

I can dot it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning, shadows}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{3mm}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5mm,
      start chain = going below,
        LA/.style = {semithick, -{Triangle[length=3mm,width=3mm,fill=white]},
                     shorten >=0.5mm, shorten <=1.5mm},
every node/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=white,
                     text width=30em, align=justify, font=\sffamily,
                     drop shadow,
                     on chain, join=by LA}%, join=by Dart}
                     ]
% Place nodes
\node {\textbf{1.} We start the CUEs service loop by computing the priority index for each CUE m and for each sub-channel $n$ according to (3.7).};
\node {\textbf{2.} We serve CUE $m$ with sub-channel n fulfilling condition (3.8).};
\node {\textbf{3.} We remove sub-channel $n$ and CUE m from the service list of TTI $t$, since we have to serve other CUEs with different (non-allocated) sub-channels.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this flowchart is very simple. nodes are in the chain and connected with triangles. therefore the main effort was to define:

- nodes style (i reduce width from `60em` to `30em`, add `drop shadow` and option `on chain` for nodes positioning, and `join` for connection between nodes)
- connection lines (used `arrows.meta` library and with "dirty hack" line degenerate to do arrow head.

**addendum:**

- in case, that this figure  is used in two column article, than you only need that the image is not to wide. its width you can limited with use `\linewidth` for width of image:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning, shadows}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text for demonstrate article text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5mm,
      start chain = going below,
        LA/.style = {semithick, -{Triangle[length=3mm,width=3mm,fill=white]},
                     shorten >=0.5mm, shorten <=1.5mm},
every node/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=white,
                     text width=\linewidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}, % changed
                     align=justify, font=\sffamily,
                     drop shadow,
                     on chain, join=by LA}%, join=by Dart}
                     ]
% Place nodes
\node {\textbf{1.} We start the CUEs service loop by computing the priority index for each CUE m and for each sub-channel $n$ according to (3.7).};
\node {\textbf{2.} We serve CUE $m$ with sub-channel n fulfilling condition (3.8).};
\node {\textbf{3.} We remove sub-channel $n$ and CUE m from the service list of TTI $t$, since we have to serve other CUEs with different (non-allocated) sub-channels.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my flowchart}
\label{fig:flowchart-1}
    \end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3727281, i add short explanation to my answer and slightly correct code (in copying was lost `\end{document}, also i remove unnecessary libraries and packages.

Comment: Do you know how can I put into the page with two columns? Thanks.

Comment: you only need to cary about of image width. so far is used `30em`, but you can use `\linewidth` for width of nodes. I will add this option to answer asap.

Comment: @user3727281, see addendum to answer. now, when you receive so complete service ... you can also vote for answer (by clicking on up-pen) :-)

Comment: Great, well done. I have voted for your answer. Thanks a lot again.